# Error run scrapy after install docker

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl from dynamic content using scrapy. I get from the internet that I must install docker. But after installing it, I always get error when I run:

```
scrapy runspider example.py
```

or other scrapy command. Then I uninstall docker. But the error is still showed. This is the error:
[image]

then I try to install pypiwin32, there is an error too:[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a `permission denied` because pip is trying to set files in a directory which need more privileges.

Try to run your console with administration privileges and executing:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Then try again to run your script, without admin privileges.

---

Edit:

If you don't want to run cmd as admin, you could try something like:

```
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

But I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: But, I don't run my cmd as administrator before

Comment: The error executing cmd as admin and executing pip install pypiwin32 is the same?